# How to read a .FIS file (MATHLAB) in Anylogic and perform FUZZY modeling using jFuzzyLogic.FIS?

Tags: anylogic, fuzzy, jfuzzylogic

Anylogic software allows the execution of .JAR classes. [JFuzzyLogic](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/) is an open source library that implements Fuzzy logic. The desire is to use Anylogic by implementing Fuzzy logic in an easy way. Is the FuzzyLogic library the most suitable tool? Is it possible to dynamically display the FUZZY chart within Anylogic?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of what you have tried so that others could be more helpful in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the FuzzyLogic library the most suitable tool?

That's a subjective question which I don't think StackOverflow can answer. But, yes, there is no fuzzy logic functionality built into AnyLogic and you can use any external Java libraries.

> Is it possible to dynamically display the FUZZY chart within Anylogic?

If the library uses Java Swing to create the chart in a window then it should work on desktop AnyLogic, but not if run in the Anylogic Cloud (easiest just to try it). *But*, because the animation of AnyLogic models (since AnyLogic 8.3) occurs in an embedded Web browser and not using Java Swing, you wouldn't be able to 'integrate' any such chart windows with the main AnyLogic model animation/UI.